# Cannot insert data in database using ajax post jquery request with codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to insert row in database using ajax jquery post method for that i am using the below code in Codeigniter, but my data is not inserted in a database.
Please help to sort out my issue.

> View:

```
$("#Submit_Course_Goal").on("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var dataString = $("form#courseGoalForm").serializeArray();
alert("datastring"+dataString);
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>create_course/create_course_goal",
    cache: false,               
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data){
    alert("data"+data);
    },
    error: function(){                      
    alert('Error while request..');
    }
 });
});

<form name="courseGoalForm" id="courseGoalForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="c_id" value="<?=$result;?>" />
<textarea data-focus="false" rows="8" name="description1"> </textarea>
<textarea data-focus="false" rows="8" name="description2">   </textarea>
<textarea data-lang="en" rows="8" name="description3">  </textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-success" id="Submit_Course_Goal" />
</form>
```

> Model:

```
public function create_course_goal($data,$id) {

   $this->load->database();
   $this->db->where('id', $id);
   $this->db->update('course', $data);
   $course_id=$id;
   if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
    return $course_id;
   }
   else
   {
   return false;
   }
}
```

> Controller:

```
public function create_course_goal(){

    $course_goal1=$this->input->post('description1');
    $course_goal2=$this->input->post('description2');
    $course_goal3=$this->input->post('description3');
    $id=$this->input->post('c_id');  

    $data=array('course_goal1'=>$course_goal1,'course_goal2'=>$course_goal2,'course_goal3'=>$course_goal3);
    $result_course = $this->course_model->create_course_goal($data,$id);

    if($result_course!='false')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Also post the value of `alert("datastring"+dataString);`

Comment: Is there any error code / error message?

Comment: Value for datastring is [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: No there is no error

Comment: Saty- but in success  section data is blank

Comment: `print_r($data)` inside your controller and check your post value

Comment: this is what gets printed dataArray
(
[course_goal1]=>
[course_goal1]=>
[course_goal1]=>
)

Comment: Saty- I think i cannot get value using post but how to get the value.

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` inside your controller and check post value!!!

Comment: this is the output : dataArray
(
[c_id]=>141
[description1]=>
[description2]=>
[description3]=>
)

Comment: You need to add `name attribute` in your text area as `name='description1'...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99463/discussion-between-user3653474-and-saty).

Comment: I can't get the value using $this->input->post('xyz');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these codes.

```
("#Submit_Course_Goal").on("click", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var description1  = $("#description1").val();
var description2  = $("#description2").val();
var description3 = $("#description3").val(); 


$.ajax({
    type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>create_course/create_course_goal",
    cache: false,               
    data: {
        desc1 : description1,
        desc2 : description2,
        desc3 : description3
    },
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(){                      
    alert('Error while request..');
    }
 });
});

<!-- Form -->

<form name="courseGoalForm" id="courseGoalForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onclick="return false">
    <input type="hidden" name="c_id" value="<?=$result;?>" />
    <textarea data-focus="false" rows="8" name="description1" id="description1"> </textarea>
    <textarea data-focus="false" rows="8" name="description2" id="description2">   </textarea>
    <textarea data-lang="en" rows="8" name="description3" id="description3">  </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-success" id="Submit_Course_Goal" />
</form>


<!-- Controller -->

<?php 

    public function create_course_goal(){



    $data=array(
        'ID' => $this->input->post('c_id'),
        'course_goal1'=> $this->input->post('desc1'),
        'course_goal2'=> $this->input->post('desc2'),
        'course_goal3'=> $this->input->post('desc3')
        );
    $result = $this->course_model->create_course_goal($data);

    if ($result) {
      echo 'success';
    }else echo 'fail';

}


/*MODEL*/

function create_course_goal($data = array())
  {
    return $this->db->insert('course',$data);

  }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this !

var dataString = $("#courseGoalForm").serialize();

instead of

var dataString = $("form#courseGoalForm").serializeArray();

Comment: Yes used but not found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Controller.

```
public function create_course_goal(){



    $data=array(
        'ID' => $this->input->post('c_id'),
        'course_goal1'=> $this->input->post('description1'),
        'course_goal2'=> $this->input->post('description2'),
        'course_goal3'=> $this->input->post('description3')
        );
    $result = $this->course_model->create_course_goal($data);

    if ($result) {
      echo 'success';
    }else echo 'fail';

}
```

Model

```
 function create_course_goal($options = array())
  {

    if(isset($options['course_goal1']))
      $this->db->set('course_goal1',$options['course_goal1']);;
    if(isset($options['course_goal2']))
      $this->db->set('course_goal2',$options['course_goal2']);;
    if(isset($options['course_goal3']))
      $this->db->set('course_goal3',$options['course_goal3']);;


    $this->db->where('ID',$options['ID']);
    $this->db->update('course');
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
  }
```

Note : course_goal1, course_goal2, course_goal3 should be same as in database. and course should be database table's name.

This was for update database if you want to insert new data use this model

```
function addNewData($data = array())
  {
    return $this->db->insert('course',$data);

  }
```

Note 2 : in your database 'id' should be primary and auto incrementing
your table name should be 'course'
and row names should be 'course_goal1', 'course_goal2', 'course_goal3'

Comment: public function testCourse(){

 $data=array(
        'ID' => '1',
        'course_goal1'=> 'test1',
        'course_goal2'=> 'test2',
        'course_goal3'=> 'test3'
        );
    $result = $this->course_model->create_course_goal($data);

    if ($result) {
      echo 'success';
    }else echo 'fail';

}

what is the result

Comment: btw are you triying to set a new record to database or update.

Comment: If i fill the field value manually i get the record inserted in the database.

Comment: like $data=array('course_goal1'=>'record1','course_goal2'=>'record2','course_goal3'=>'record3');

Comment: Enes- I found the problem actually its textarea i am getting value from textbox but cannot get value from textarea how to solve this

Comment: give textarea an id and get its value 

var description1 = $('#description1').val();
var description2 = $('#description2').val();
var description3 = $('#description3').val();

and change data in ajax 

data : { des1 : description1, des2 : description2 , desc3 : description3 }

Comment: but for security reason i want to use post

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing method='post' from the Form and submit your data with ajax

Comment: I have to submit it using post method

Comment: YOu are already doing it by ajax why are you adding it two times?

Comment: I am getting value from textbox but cannot get value using textarea

Comment: have you used network tab in web console to see whether the value is submitting via post or not?

Comment: This
`<input type="hidden" name="c_id" value="<?=$result;?>" />`
Should be like this
`<input type="hidden" name="c_id" value="<?php echo $result;?>" />`